# Swing GUI throws Exception while trying to change the GUI in real time

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

So i have a swing GUI where i change it's default look and feel based upon some input from another GUI Class using something like this:

```
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("newlook&feel");
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
pack();
```

This works fine, but however on the console i see everytime this is called an exception is thrown with message like:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and it refers to line numbers from classes which are internal Java classes. What could be the problem here or i am missing something.

Just a point, `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` returns `false` in this scenario.

Comment: could you give us the full exception trace and your class definition?

Comment: @shybovycha, it would be too lengthy basically what i do is call a static method of this GUI class from another class and update a static variable. Once it is updated, i invoke a GUI Look and Feel Update method in this class, which basically runs the above 3 lines of code to update. It works fine, but i see lot of exceptions in console which are from java internal classes. Here is the error log: http://www.file-upload.net/download-4004773/log.txt.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Just a point, SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() returns false in
>   this scenario.

Maybe that is the problem, have you tried invoking the L&F change inside the EDT Thread?

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("newlook&feel");
         SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(OuterClassName.this);
         pack();
        }
      });
```

Comment: thanks but problem is with this, i get compile time error saying the method updateComponentTreeUI() in the type
swingUtilities is not applicable for the arguments(new Runnable(){})

Comment: @Wojtek O. You are on the right track with the problem, but when you reference this inside the new Runnable() it does not pass the outer object as you expect. You will need to pass the outer object manually inside the new Runnable and call the method with that object as a parameter.

Comment: @Johnydep: because `this` here resolves to the Runnable. You'll need to use something like `MyJFrame.this` to refer to your frame. Otherwise, this solution should work for you.

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer, should be ok now. Just make sure you change the `OuterClassName` with the proper name of your outer class.

Comment: Hi, thanks it worked. Actually the problem was not with "this". I simply removed the semicolon after pack(); }; and instead of last curly brcket added });

Comment: Edited this as well so someone can benefit from this sample in the future.